# Android Studio doesn't show import suggestion

Tags: android-studio

[image: Click here to see bug]

[image: No module suggestion for import command]

After trying adding the GSON library with "compile 'com.google...' ",I get a situation that when I try to import modules the IDE suggest me nothing except static and *. So I have to type everything. How can I fix it? I created new projects and still get this problem.

Comment: Consider adding a highlight to the problem in the screenshot provided by you and add more details to the question. Question is still not understandable.

Comment: fixed the question :D @HarshitAgrawal

Comment: still I can not see what the problem is. Red circle the area in the screenshot

Comment: take a look once more

Comment: In that case, just press Alt+Enter when you are writing the code. The IDE will automatically import the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're in 21 century and using modern IDE Android Studio. Why do you want to import packages manually just like we import when writing code in simple Notepad or any other text editor?

Just type the name of class which you want to use in your code. And the IDE is smart enough to show the suggestions which relates to your typed keyword.

> I get a situation that when i try to import modules the IDE suggest me nothing except **static** and *.

Yes, it's indeed. Here is my screenshot

[image: screenshot 1]

> How can I fix it?

Very simple. Just type class name whatever you want and select it from suggestions. Android Studio automatically imports it.

For example (as per your requirement) you want to import `@SerializedName()` annotation. Type `@Ser` and hit `Ctrl + Space` and see the magic.

[image: screenshot 2]

Now the Android Studio showing me the suggestions which matches with keyword `Ser` and I'll select `SerializedName (com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName)`. That's it.

Hope it'll be helpful.